# JSON Array mapping in ReactJS from request

Tags: reactjs

Currently i'm rewriting a class component to a function component. I need to do this since i need to use the useSelector hook from redux. Now i'm getting pretty close but i'm having some trouble with the json array getting mapped. It's letting me know it's not a function. In the fetch i'm logging the leaderboard which has returned. This gives me the json i was expecting.

```
[
  {
    "ID": 1,
    "teamName": "Developers",
    "time": "19:54"
  },
  {
    "ID": 1591621934400,
    "teamName": "h435hfg",
    "time": "19:54"
  }
]
```

Then here is my code that im having trouble with:

```
import React, {useEffect, useState} from 'react';
import '../style/App.scss';
import {useSelector} from "react-redux";

function Leaderboard() {

    const io = require('socket.io-client');
    const socket = io.connect("http://localhost:3001/", {
        reconnection: false
    });
    const [leaderboard, setLeaderboard] = useState([]);

    const timerState = useSelector(state => state.timerState);


    useEffect(() => {
        socket.emit("addTeamToLeaderboard", getTeam());

        fetch('http://localhost:3000/leaderboard')
            .then(response => response.json())
            .then(leaderboard => {
                leaderboard.push(getTeam()); // this is just so your team score renders the first time
                setLeaderboard({leaderboard})
                console.log(leaderboard)
            });
    }, [socket]);

    const getTeam = () => {
        let team = JSON.parse(sessionStorage.getItem('currentTeam')) ;
        team.time = timerState;
        return team;
    }

    const leaderboardElements = leaderboard.map((data, key) => {
        return (
            <tr key={key} className={ data.ID === getTeam().ID ? "currentTeam" : "" }>
                <td>{data.teamName}</td>
                <td>{data.time}</td>
            </tr>
        )
    })

    return (
            <div>
                <h1>Leaderboard</h1>
                <table className="leaderboard">
                    <tr>
                        <th>Team</th>
                        <th>Time</th>
                    </tr>
                    {leaderboardElements}
                </table>
            </div>
        );

}

export default Leaderboard;
```

The old code which im rewriting:

```
import React from 'react';
import '../style/App.scss';

class Leaderboard extends React.Component {
    state = {
        leaderboard: []
    }

    compare(a, b) {
        if (a.time < b.time) {
            return -1;
        }
        if (a.time > b.time) {
            return 1;
        }
        return 0;
    }

    getTeam(){
        let team = JSON.parse(sessionStorage.getItem('currentTeam')) ;
        team.time = 12.13; //Todo add actual playing time
        return team;
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        const io = require('socket.io-client');
        const socket = io.connect("http://localhost:3001/", {
            reconnection: false
        });

        socket.emit("addTeamToLeaderboard", this.getTeam());

        fetch('http://localhost:3000/leaderboard')
            .then(response => response.json())
            .then(leaderboard => {
                leaderboard.push(this.getTeam()); // this is just so your team score renders the first time
                this.setState({ leaderboard })
            });
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <h1>Leaderboard</h1>
                <table className="leaderboard">
                    <tr>
                        <th>Team</th>
                        <th>Time</th>
                    </tr>
                    {
                        this.state.leaderboard.sort(this.compare).map((data, key) => {
                            return (
                                <tr key={key} className={ data.ID == this.getTeam().ID ? "currentTeam" : "" }>
                                    <td>{data.teamName}</td>
                                    <td>{data.time}</td>
                                </tr>
                            )
                        })
                    }
                </table>
            </div>
        );
    }

}

export default Leaderboard;
```

Comment: you should not use socket in useEffect like [socket], it only reruns if socket changes, so the reference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not following why you are changing `leaderboard` data type. If it is an array you shouldn't do `setLeaderboard({leaderboard})` because you are assigning an object to the state.

You should pass a new array to the `setLeaderboard` like:

```js
setLeaderboard([...leaderboard]);
```

Also if you do

```js
setLeaderboard([...leaderboard]);
console.log(leaderboard);
```

You will not get the updated state right in the log, because set state is an asynchronous call.

Another tip, I would highly recommend you to put the socket connection not in the `useEffect` function, put outside the functional component.

```
const io = require('socket.io-client');
const socket = io.connect("http://localhost:3001/", {
  reconnection: false
});

function Leaderboard() {
  ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

*It's letting me know it's not a function*

```
/* fetch data */

leaderboard.push(getTeam()); 
setLeaderboard({leaderboard}) // => change to setLeaderboard(leaderboard.concat(getTeam()))
console.log(leaderboard)

/* other functions below */
```

the difference between `setState` and the `setLeaderboard` that is returned from `useState` is that (when giving none callback argument)

- `setState` expects an object with {[key: stateYouAreChanging]: [value: newState],
- `setLeaderboard` expects the newStatValue as the argument.

So your code above is setting `leaderboard` state to be an object with that looks like this

```
leaderboard = {
  leaderboard: NEW_LEADERBOARD_FETCHED_FROM_REQUEST
}
```